# How to work around a lack of an `IN` clause in Firebase Query with a query for 500 filters

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I need to create a typical find friends feature in my mobile app that's using Firebase.  The user would upload a list of hashed contact emails or phone numbers from their address book and the server would return a list of usernames that are already using the application.  The typical user would have around 500 contacts in their address book.

This would be pretty straightforward to set up using a traditional SQL or Mongo database but in Firebase this would be difficult because I don't see any `WHERE IN` clauses with Firebase Query and it seems like it would be very inefficient using a Firebase Database for this.  Even if I created a specific HashedPhoneNumbers collection with the hash being the id, it still seems like a monster query.  Is there a way to make this query run efficiently in Firebase?

i.e. `SELECT username from Users WHERE phoneHash IN [list of 500 phone hashes]`

Alternatively, if I were to use Google Cloud DataStore looks like it supports chaining a bunch of `AND email_hash = XXX` filters together, but I don't know how efficient that would be if the filter list is 500 filters chained together.

Comment: This is really an opinion type question and while there is an answer, you should take a few hours and go through the Firebase getting started guide. Maybe craft up a small project to see how firebase works. It can easily handle what you are asking - the tricky bit is how you compare new contacts with ones you already have stored; via email? phone? something else? You should be using the Firebase Database to store your contacts. #3 is unclear but the key to Firebase is how you structure your data so you don't have to have 200 filters.

Comment: I've already created a few applications with Firebase and am fairly certain that #1 is not viable since it doesn't have an `IN` clause... but wanted to make sure with this post.  So in all likely hood I'll have to use something else.  I know how to do it using #2, but was wondering if there is a complementary effect of staying in the Google Cloud eco-system since Firebase is now part of Google.  There has to be 300 filters since a typical user has 300 phone numbers or emails in their address book.

Comment: I just re-did the question to ask less opinions since it seemed like it was distracting from the core question.. so now it's just pointedly asking about the IN clause efficiency

Comment: While there is no direct 'in' clause, there are many ways to structure your data to get results that are usable and scaleable. We have similar queries to what you are asking about and they were not hard to implement, were efficient and blisteringly fast. It's a little unclear what the specific use case is though; why would usernames need to be queried by 300 phone numbers when those already exist in the users address book? Take the case of an existing user adding a friend; the user they would be adding would already exist in Firebase with a uid so that uid could be added to their friends list.

Comment: The use case is find friends, so: "out of the 300 people in any user's address book, how many of them are already in our database?"  We don't store the user's address book in any way so those hashes of 300 friends phone numbers (in which only a handful might exist in our users collection) only go over the wire and are never persisted.

Comment: Is this when the user first uses the app? i.e. they just downloaded the app  and want to upload those 300 people? Any new users would would have a UID which would be persisted in Firebase. If this is a case of determining if a friend that's stored locally already exists, it's going to be tricky from a design standpoint as you have to assume a key of some kind - is it the phone? email? A friend could have different phone numbers and emails so that might not be reliable. I may be better to add people as friends that already exist in Firebase.

Comment: It would be on first use or anytime after when they hit the find friends button.  Some of them would exist because some of their friends would have already signed up for the service before them.  We would not be matching on UID, and instead be matching on hashed phone numbers since the address book has no knowledge of UID.  The key is the hashed phone number.   Yes, they could have registered with a private or different phone number, but that's ok - it doesn't have to catch 100% of all edge cases.

Comment: You could for example store the 'new' 300 users in a node with phone number as a key. Then it's a snap to load the usernames. You could store the phone number as a child and query for each one. While there is more overhead, it's also not a big deal. Firebase is fully capable of handling this use case, however, if you feel SQL would be a better solution that would also do the job.

Comment: well I couldn't store the 500 phone hashes - since they are not registered users and is in fact the users address book - and they only exist in the call coming over the wire.  If the performance of checking the 500 phone hashes against a firebase collection of millions of users is not a performance bottleneck - I'll go with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it does. For that i recomand you to see: [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [NoSQL Data Modeling Techniques](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).
2. It's it does not support this kind of query but there method with which you can achieve the same thing. Explained in the above tutorial.
3. Yes it does. For this i recomand you to use [Cloud Storage For Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/).

As a conclusion, i kindly recomand you using `Firebase`.

Comment: I don't see in the links or docs anywhere an efficient `IN` clause, and the NO SQL modeling doesn't seem to address it anywhere either.  Which technique in specific were you referring to?

Comment: You don't see an `IN` clause because there is no `IN` clause. In this case i recomand you starting with the basics of Firebase. The official documentation is a very good starting point.

Comment: That was my point, that it has no `IN` clause.  The question was how to work around it.  Your answer seemed to suggest that it did have one.

Comment: I said that in Firebase there is no `IN` clause but you can achieve the same thing using related methods. The line of code: `SELECT username from Users WHERE phoneHash IN [list of 500 phone hashes]` can be translated in Firebase like this: `Attach a listener on the node that contains the list of 500 phone hashes. Get those numbers from the dataSnapshot object. Based on those numbers get all user names.` Try not to think in terms of a SQL database, try to think in terms of a NoSQL database, a JSON database.

Comment: but I can't get the data snapshot because the users node has millions of user nodes.  Wouldn't it try to download or scan through the entire list- that's the performance bottleneck I'm worried about.

Comment: There is no problem within Firebase to have millions of user nodes. It is true that in Firebase in not a good practice to download the entire user node because it would be a waste of bandwith and performance but there is a method with which you can solve this problem and is called `denormalization`. For this i recomand you see the following tutorial for a better understanding: [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA). So you don't need to be worried about this.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Can i help you with other informations?

Comment: At this point, based on the discussions,  it seems like it's really a question of: is the performance of checking for the existance of 500 keys against a firebase collection reference of millions of hashes in a single user button click a performance bottleneck.